# Concatenating to DataFrame will gives two separate start Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe read from two `csv` file.

```
train = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DIU\Desktop\ML-titanic\train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DIU\Desktop\ML-titanic\test.csv")
```

In `train` dataframe i have **891** rows and in `test` dataframe i have **418** rows.

I concatenate this two dataframe into a new dataframe `full_data`.

```
full_data = pd.concat([train, test])
```

`full_data` now contains **1309** rows, BUT the problem is, the default generated `index` are separate for both dataframe. Both `index` are started from one.

BUT i want the `test` dataframe index should start from 892 instead of 0.

How do i do that?

Comment: Note, you can always `.reset_index`

Answer (score 3):

Use parameter `ignore_index=True` in [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
full_data = pd.concat([train, test], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:
`full_data = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)`